# UIPageViewController pageIndex not decreasing correctly

Tags: ios, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController in my app with the following methods:

```
-(ChildViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (([self.pageImages count] == 0) || (index >= [self.pageImages count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
    ChildViewController *pageContentViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ChildViewController"];

    pageContentViewController.imageFile = self.pageImages[index];
    pageContentViewController.bodyText = self.pageBody[index];
    pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;


    NSLog(@"Index: %i", index);

    return pageContentViewController;

}


- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerBeforeViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((ChildViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if ((index == 0) || (index == NSNotFound)) {
        return nil;
    }

    index--;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}

- (UIViewController *)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController viewControllerAfterViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
    NSUInteger index = ((ChildViewController*) viewController).pageIndex;

    if (index == NSNotFound || (index == [self.pageImages count])) {
        return nil;
    }

    index++;

    return [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];
}
```

The problem I am having is that even though the pageViewController is working correctly, when I try to NSLog the index of the page I get some strange values.
When I am going forward,  the index increments correctly but when I try to go back a page the index jumps instead of decrementing as expected.

Here is the console read-out:

```
2015-01-02 16:11:13.808 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 0
2015-01-02 16:11:15.305 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 1
2015-01-02 16:11:15.677 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 2
2015-01-02 16:11:17.071 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 3
2015-01-02 16:11:18.356 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 4
2015-01-02 16:11:20.006 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 5
2015-01-02 16:11:21.806 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 2
2015-01-02 16:11:32.075 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 5
2015-01-02 16:11:33.458 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 2
2015-01-02 16:11:35.708 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 5
2015-01-02 16:11:36.943 iPregrancy+[12495:1837301] Index: 2
```

Any ideas/suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using transition style `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll`?  If so, I think the behaviour is due to the UIPageViewController caching the view controllers.

Say you are on the page with index 3, and you swipe left.  The PVC will request (through `viewControllerAfterViewController`) the VC after index 3.  Your code returns the VC at index 4. But the page view controller also requests the VC after index 4 (even before you start to swipe).  So you return index 5 - but this is not displayed by the PVC unless you swipe left again.

If instead you swipe right (whilst it is still displaying index 4), it still has a reference to the VC that comes before index 4 (i.e. index 3), so it displays that.  But, again, it also requests the VC before index 3 - so you return the page at index 2 (but this is not displayed unless you swipe right a second time).

The result is that, if you swap back and forth between index 3 and index 4, the VCs you will see being requested are index 2 and index 5 - as per your log.

I assume the page view controller does this "pre-emptive loading" in order to avoid delay if the user keeps swiping rapidly in the same direction.  But, to conclude, I don't think what you have observed is anything to worry about.

**EDIT**

If you want to keep track of the index that is currently being displayed, use the `willTransitionToViewControllers:` and `didFinishAnimating:` delegate methods.  Something like:

```
-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController willTransitionToViewControllers:(NSArray *)pendingViewControllers {
    if ([pendingViewControllers[0] isKindOfClass:[ChildViewController class]]) {
        ChildViewController *nextVC = (ChildViewController *)pendingViewControllers[0];
        self.nextIndex = nextVC.pageIndex;
    }
}

-(void)pageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController didFinishAnimating:(BOOL)finished previousViewControllers:(NSArray *)previousViewControllers transitionCompleted:(BOOL)completed {
    if (completed) {
        // transition to next VC completed successfully
        self.currentIndex = self.nextIndex;
    } else {
        // transition was aborted
        self.nextIndex = self.currentIndex;
    }
}
```

You will need to add properties for `currentIndex` and `nextIndex`, and also to set the `delegate` of the page view controller (in the same place as you currently set the `dataSource`).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! How can I get the current page index to use with something I am doing in the parent view controller?

Comment: I will update my answer, but the gist is to use the PVC's delegate methods, willTransitionToVC and didFinishAnimating to keep track of which index is actually being displayed.

Comment: Perfect and complete answer. Thank you